# Handling failed claim in Nancy

Tags: nancy

I am using the RequiresClaims mechanism in Nancy like this:

```
public class HomeModule : NancyModule
{
    public HomeModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = ctx => "<a href=\"/admin\">Go here</a>";

        Get["/admin"] = ctx =>
        {
            this.RequiresClaims(new[] { "boss" });    // this
            return "Hello!";
        };

        Get["/login"] = ctx => "<form action=\"/login\" method=\"post\">" +
            "<button type=\"submit\">login</button>" +
            "</form>";

        Post["/login"] = ctx =>
        {
            return this.Login(Guid.Parse("332651DD-A046-4489-B31F-B6FA1FB290F0"));
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is if the user is not allowed to enter `/admin` because the user doesn't have claim `boss`, Nancy just responds with http status 403 and blank body.

This is exactly what I need for the web service part of my application, but there are also parts of my application where nancy should construct page for user. How can I show something more informative to the user?

This is the user mapper that I use:

```
public class MyUserMapper : IUserMapper
{
    public class MyUserIdentity : Nancy.Security.IUserIdentity
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> Claims { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public Nancy.Security.IUserIdentity GetUserFromIdentifier(Guid identifier, Nancy.NancyContext context)
    {
        return new MyUserIdentity { UserName = "joe", Claims = new[] { "peon" } };
    }
}
```

And this is the bootstrapper that I use:

```
public class MyNancyBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void RequestStartup(
        Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCContainer container, Nancy.Bootstrapper.IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
    {
        base.RequestStartup(container, pipelines, context);

        var formAuthConfig = new Nancy.Authentication.Forms.FormsAuthenticationConfiguration
        {
            RedirectUrl = "~/login",
            UserMapper = container.Resolve<Nancy.Authentication.Forms.IUserMapper>()
        };

        Nancy.Authentication.Forms.FormsAuthentication.Enable(pipelines, formAuthConfig);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the 403 status code as part of the pipeline and then return an html response to the user. Take a look at http://paulstovell.com/blog/consistent-error-handling-with-nancy